# Bitbucket - sending two pull requests in a row, PR merged

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've sent two pull requests to some project from the same branch (but that were different functionalities - my bad) and the same fork, is it normal that those pull requests got merged and are shown as one on destination project?

How to avoid this? Changing branch for each functionality is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is normal, if you updated the older pull request and all commits were on the same branch.

To avoid this in future, create feature branches and then send individual pull request from the respective feature branch.